# $('div'); returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to get all the div classes in a page using jQuery `$('div');`, it's on a page that doesn't support jquery but I load it using the links below until I get `$ === jQuery` is true.

Even here on SO which has jQuery, when I do `var x = $('post-text');` `x` is empty. What might be the reason for this not working?

I do this in Chrome's console.

[How to run jQuery directly on any page in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508514/how-to-run-jquery-directly-on-any-page-in-the-browser)

[testing jQuery statements in Chrome JavaScript console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821703/testing-jquery-statements-in-chrome-javascript-console)

Comment: `post-text` is not a tag name. Is the DOM loaded before you execute `$('div');`?

Comment: `$('.post-text')` this worked

Comment: @Xufox by DOM you mean to load jQuery?

Comment: No. The DOM is not jQuery.

Comment: @Xufox Well the page did load completely, so I assume the DOM did too. How do you check if it was loaded?

Comment: Look up `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use '.' before the class name and '#' before the id name of element as $('.classname') for accessing any html element

You  can add jquery by adding it's online link in your head tag and with without adding jquery in your page you can't use it's features

Comment: What about the div selector? Why that is empty?

Comment: because you need to add jquery in your page to get the element using $('element')

Answer (score 1):

var x = $('post-text');  seems wrong

append a . or # for class or ID

var x = $('.post-text');
OR
var x = $('#post-text');

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like jQuery might not be included on the page. I have fallen victim to this before - Chrome console has a built-in selector engine also defined as $, meaning that when jQuery is not loaded on a page, $(...) can be used to do a DOM lookup.

Use $.fn.jquery in order to find out the version of jQuery loaded. It should return something like "1.7.1" but the version you have. If it isn't defined, jQuery isn't loaded.

Comment: I get 1.11.1 on that page from `$.fn.jquery`

Comment: Are you using the jQuery on ready function to make sure you're executing after jQuery is loaded? Also, when I do `$('div')` on SO I get results.

Comment: It's not on SO, I just tested it here. I load jquery using the links in my question and run the commands in chrome console.

Comment: Anyway looks like jquery does work there, I wasn't using the dot selector.

Comment: Sounds like @sheetal has the correct answer. Feel free to make it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score -2):

first you add jquery file in page like this

```
var jquery = document.createElement('script'); 
jquery.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.head.appendChild(jquery);
```

now you can use all jquery functions

```
alert($('div').length);
```